# How to pass response to a spider without fetching a web page?

Tags: scrapy

[The scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#downloader-middlewares) specifically mentions that I should use downloader middleware if I want to pass a response to a spider without actually fetching the web page. However, I can't find any documentation or examples on how to achieve this functionality.

I am interested in passing only the url to the request callback, populate an item's `file_urls` field with the url (and certain permutations thereof), and use the FilesPipeline to handle the actual download.

How can a write a downloader middleware class that passes the url to the spider while avoiding downloading the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `Response` object in downloader middleware's `process_request()` method. This method is called for every request your spider yields.

Something like:

```
class NoDownloadMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # only process marked requests
        if not request.meta.get('only_download'):
            return
        # now make Response object however you wish
        response = Response(request.url)
        return response
```

and in your spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield Request(some_url, meta={'only_download':True})
```

and in your `settings.py` activate the middleware:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.NoDownloadMiddleware': 543,
}
```